# Need Custom error or exception thrown from AspNetCoreRateLimit library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, rate-limiting

I want custom error thrown. In json format like this

```
{
 "message":"API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted 2 per 1m.",
 "status": 429
}
```

Currently I am getting error in string format.
[image]

my **Startup.cs**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            //app.UseMiddleware<RateLimitException>();
        }

        //add the IP rate limiting middleware to the HTTP request-response pipeline.
        app.UseIpRateLimiting();
```

Comment: based on their [doc](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#setup) , u can override the **IpRateLimitMiddleware.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [document](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#setup) said:

> *You can customize the response by changing these options HttpStatusCode and QuotaExceededMessage, if you want to implement your
> own response you can override the
> IpRateLimitMiddleware.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse. The Retry-After
> header value is expressed in seconds.*

Then, you could refer the following solution from [this link](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/70).

Create a MyIPRateLimitMiddleware with the following code:

```
public class MyIPRateLimitMiddleware : IpRateLimitMiddleware
    {
        public MyIPRateLimitMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<IpRateLimitOptions> options, IRateLimitCounterStore counterStore, IIpPolicyStore policyStore, IRateLimitConfiguration config, ILogger<IpRateLimitMiddleware> logger) : base(next, options, counterStore, policyStore, config, logger)
        {
        }

        public override Task ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(HttpContext httpContext, RateLimitRule rule, string retryAfter)
        {
          //  return base.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(httpContext, rule, retryAfter);
            string str = string.Format("API calls quata exceeded! maximum maximum admitted {0} per {1}", rule.Limit,
                rule.Period);
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {error = str});
            httpContext.Response.Headers["Retry-After"] = retryAfter;
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

Then in the Startup.Configure method, remove the `app.UseIpRateLimiting();`, and add the following code before any middleware.

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyIPRateLimitMiddleware>();
```

Besides, you can also try to set the QuotaExceededResponse configuration.

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
        "......":"......",
        "QuotaExceededResponse": {
            "ContentType": "application/json",
            "Content": "{{\"error\":\"API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted {0} per {1}.\"}}"
        }
    }
```

Reference: [Rest api json response](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/70) and [Configurable ReturnQuotaExceededResponse content](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/14).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for.